# How to get long the image is hovered?

Tags: java, android, time, ontouchlistener

I want to get long the image is hovered 
and i tried this:

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                Long start = null, end = null;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                       //do somethins....
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        //do something...
                        break;
                }
                if(end-start<1003){
                     //do something ....
                  }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

but it gives me a null exception ,what can i do to make it to work?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you null pointer exception because you're using "end" and "start" while they're still null. Also, ACTION_DOWN happens before ACTION UP. ACTION_DOWN fires when you first touch the view, while ACTION_UP fires when you lift your finger.

Also, you have to define your variables outside the onTouch method, or else they won't ever be both initialized because ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP never get called at the same time.

```
Long start = 0L, end = 0L;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //do something....
            if(end-start<1003){
                     //do something ....
            }
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //do something...         
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your `start` or `end` objects will be null on every execution of this method. If the action is UP, then `end` is never initialized before you try to compute with it. If the action is DOWN, then `start` is never initialized before you try to compute with it.

You could make the start/end variables larger in scope, such as by defining them as class variables. That way, presumably, both variables will be initialized to values before any calculation is attempted with them.

Comment: thank you Kon but i know what the problem is and i'am searching for the answer , the question is : How to get long the image is hovered?

Answer (score -2):

Just change this line

`Long start = null, end = null;`

to

```
       Long start =0L;
       Long  end = 0L;
```

Comment: Will give you garbage data on first run.